Кавычки в названиях оружия
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли кавычки в названиях оружия в художественных текстах?
Например: Меч "Стрела"
А также, если данное название употребляется без слова "меч", как следует написать?
Например: Он вновь достал "Стрелу" из ножен.

Это может быть имя меча - уникальное оружие, а не название марки-модели меча - то что в кавычках. Меч с заглавной буквы сомнительное написание.


Можно купить меч или нож в магазине: 1 510 ₽ −68%
Осталось 5 шт

Метательный нож Стрела TS070-30FN. Меч Стрела.

В тексте уместно упрощенное написание со строчой буквы в кавычках: Он вновь достал "стрелу" из ножен. При отсутствии родового слова меч название в кавычках склоняется.

